# How to localize google maps api so that each country uses local names

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I localize the map so that each county, city etc. is displayed with its local name. I need to localize the map and also the reverse geocode results.

Something like what [wikimedia](https://maps.wikimedia.org/) does:

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization

Comment: read it before, it's no it. I want to localize each country to its own language and not all countries to one language. The documentation only shows how to do the later.

Comment: Hey, as far as I can tell this isn't possible from any API parameters. At best, perhaps you can hook up a custom tileset here but I don't think you can replicate the wikimedia map.

Comment: "its", not "it's". Better still: "...each country uses local names"